# Visual Composer Standalone?

Tags: wordpress, editor

Im looking to find a drag + drop editor that doesnt use wordpress.  Visual Composer seems to be the best one out there but as far as I can tell I cannot use it just on a bespoke website, it has be integrated into wordpress.

Can anyone recommend something similar that I can use?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What features do you need? Shall it integrate with Wordpress (as your tags suggest) or not (as the text says)? What is your price limit (if it comes to paid solutions), must it allow for commercial use?

Comment: I don't understand.  You want to edit a wordpress site, with a different editor than the built in one?  There are plugins that give you alternative editors.